# Is possible to make virtual host in a NTFS partition?

Tags: server, apache2, ntfs, chmod, virtualhost

I am using Ubuntu and Windows. When I use Windows, i can't access my file in `var/www` of my Linux partition. So I try to make virtual host and DirectoryRoot in my NTFS partition.

I will combine WAMP directory in the Windows, and the virtual host root directory on Ubuntu, but it does not work. Always appears `error 403 forbidden access`. And when i change the permissions with `chmod` nothing change.

What should I do?

Comment: The error appears in Windows, in Ubuntu, or in both OS?

Comment: @Lucio in ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Settings for NTFS partition**

First you need to be able to access your NTFS partition via Ubuntu. Do the following steps if you haven't.

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

Find the name of your NTFS partition(s). Example:

```
sudo fdisk -l | grep NTFS
```

Get the UUID of your NTFS partition.

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="windows" UUID="4ED2A451B2A23F59" TYPE="ntfs"
```

Configure the partition in /etc/fstab (make a backup just in case).

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak
sudo vim /etc/fstab
```

I created mine as follows (based on the UUID. The following options set read, write, execute permissions and uid=1000 sets you as the user of the NTFS partition during OS boot. This will also ensure that Apache user can access your virtual host direction (this is what solved my problem).

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/4ED2A451B2A23F59 /media/windows ntfs-3g defaults,permissions,users,uid=1000,utf8  0 0
```

If you want to mount the partition as the `www-data` user instead, then find the `www-data` user id and replace `uid=1000` with that:

```
id -u www-data
```

Note that you may need to create /media/windows directory if it doesn't exist.

```
cd /media
sudo mkdir windows
sudo chown sagun:users windows
```

Reboot your computer and confirm that your NTFS drive automounts with read, write, execute permissions enabled.

**Settings for configuring Virtual Host in Apache**

Create directories to place your log files (if you want):

```
sudo mkdir /var/log/apache2/projects.dev
```

Create a new config file inside /etc/apache2/sites-available directory. Example:

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/projects.dev.conf
```

Set your configuration similar to this and save the file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@projects.dev
    ServerName projects.dev
    ServerAlias projects
    DocumentRoot /media/windows/Users/sagun/Dropbox/projects
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AuthType None
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /media/windows/Users/sagun/Dropbox/projects/>
        Require all granted
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AuthType None
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/projects.dev/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/projects.dev/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Next, edit the /etc/hosts file.

```
sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

Add the following line and save:

```
127.0.0.1   projects.dev
```

Activate the host with the following command:

```
sudo a2ensite projects.dev
```

Restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Finally I was able to go to `http://projects.dev` from my Browser with all my code residing in NTFS partition from both Windows and Ubuntu. I hope someone finds this useful. Cheers!

Comment: no working for me, I still get `403 forbidden`. My `vhost.conf` is same as yours (except paths & servername). Also the partition is mounted with `0777` permissions (`drwxrwxrwx 1 daithi root`). I'm going to try mount the partition as `daithi:www-data`, so me & apache group will have read/write, not sure if its possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to fix the problem

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89118/apache-gives-me-403-access-forbidden-when-documentroot-points-to-two-different-d

Basically you need an entry like this in your httpd.conf file

```
<Directory "physical path to the directory">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
    # Any other directory-specific stuff
</Directory>
```

Comment: I've already done that, but still no change. error appears in ubuntu. in windows that's ok.

Comment: After adding that, have you tried restarting Apache?

Comment: sure, what you mean physical path is the same with path working directory (PWD) in terminal??

Comment: For example, /mnt/CDRIVE/ePubRoot/MyWebsite

Comment: DocumentRoot /media/rslhdyt/Document/wamp/www/

Comment: Apache process should have read and execute permission over all those directories media, rslhdyt, Document, wamp and www

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for me was to change the Apache user, this can take a bit of risk, but it worked well for me.

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/envvars
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set up your hard drive to be mounted automatically, probably the editing process to envvars not work because the partition will be in /mnt.

This procedure may not be as secure, but it worked for min. I left the www-data user even in envvars and added the apache user to the root group.

```
sudo usermod -G root www-data
```

How it works only locally, I believe that there are no major risks.